# gcd of $2$ numbers with multiplying on any prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

We have two numbers $a$ and $b$ and $\gcd(a, b)$. We can multiply one of these numbers on any prime number. We need to get the most possible gcd. How can we do that?

I had an idea like take all the prime numbers between $1$ and $\max(a, b) / \min(a, b)$ and check all the gcd's with these prime numbers and take the biggest. But this theory is not working if we have for example $a = 100500$ and $b = 500100$ because $b / a = 4$, but the right answer is $1667$ because of $\gcd(500100, 100500\cdot 1667)$ is $500100$, but my answer is $1500$. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please use mathjax, in this case dollar signs,  and `not` `this` " \` " surrounding expressions.

Comment: $\gcd(100500,500100)=300$ and  looking for possible primes $\frac{100500}{300}=5 \times 67$ while $\frac{500100}{300}=1667$.  The largest of these is $1667$ and so the one to use.  [I prefer to use "hcf" for *highest common factor* but anyway]

Comment: @Henry you mean that our prime numbers range should be in $2...\frac{max(a,b)}{gcd(a,b)}$ or I didn't understand it correctly?

Comment: I am saying that you only need to consider $5$ or $67$ or $1667$ and it is obvious which one is biggest

Comment: I just wanna try to use it in code but it will take a lot of time to make a loop with 1667 numbers and check every number

Comment: The GCD of any number with a prime will always be either or that prime itself. Also as Henry is saying, divisibility is transitive: if $c$ is divisible by $b$, and $b$ is divisible by $a$, then you instantly know that $c$ will also already be divisible by $a$

Comment: If you're trying to find a fast way to take GCDs, (I think) that the Euclidean algorithm, is almost counterintuitively, faster than (essentially) finding all the prime factors and powers of prime factors that will divide them -

Comment: is $b/a$ meant to mean division, too?

Comment: $\gcd(500100,100500)=300$ - according to mathematica (oops sorry didn't see Henry already said this)

Comment: I mean that I did something like that: compute $gcd(a,b)$. compute $\frac{max(a,b)}{gcd(a,b)}$, and then I took a loop in range $\frac{max(a,b)}{gcd(a,b)}$ to find the greatest possible gcd. I don't understand how I can do it faster?

Comment: 1667 is not even a divisor of both numbers, nevertheless a greatest one. Let me think about your comment...

Comment: oh by "$/$" do you mean mod? I was like wait, $500100/100500$ isn't four! my bad

Comment: stop. I didnt mean mod, I meand division

Comment: but my idea is wrong) I want to optimize Henry's solution

Comment: @Jack sorry. ok I see now, $500100/100500\approx4.97$, but you take 4 because there is no integer between 4 and 5 (i guess, or something like that)

Comment: Consider that if $a$ and $c$ share no factors, then gcd of $a$ with whatever $b$ is going to give you the same thing as with $bc$. By multiplying with anything relatively prime to, you can generate absurdly large counterexamples...

Comment: -actually wait, scratch that; think of it is this way, just because the quotient of two numbers is bounded doesn't mean that their GCD is. This is actually quite strange at first.

Comment: Exactly. But my solution didnt work with 100500 and 500100 and then Henry suggested not to take integer number from $\frac{500100}{100500}$ but to take $\frac{max(100500,500100)}{gcd(100500,500100)}$ and then I really got 1667. But the promleb is that not neccesarly 1667 must be an answer. For example, $gcd(a*1024,b) or gcd(a,b*1024)$ can be bigger than $gcd(a*1667,b) or gcd(a,b*1667)$ and I think it will take a lot of time to go throught all the numbers in range $1...1667$ and take the greatest result of gcd. I want to optimize it but don't know how

Comment: @Henry but if we will take 12,54: $gcd(12,54) = 6$, $\frac{12}{6} = 2$, $\frac{54}{6} = 9$ but the answer is 18, not 6 or 2 or 9

Comment: You said primes, so $\frac{12}{6}=2, \frac{54}{6}=3\times 3$ and $3$ is bigger than $2$ so use $3$ to multiply $6$ and get $18$

Comment: @Henry "gcd(100500,500100)=300 and looking for possible primes 100500300=5×67 while 500100300=1667. The largest of these is 1667 and so the one to use. " I don't understand what's up with the whole 1667 thing somehow

Answer (score 1):

$\gcd(1,5)=1$

$\gcd(2\cdot1,2\cdot5)=2$

$\gcd(3\cdot1,3\cdot5)=3$

$\gcd(4\cdot1,4\cdot5)=4$

$\gcd(5\cdot1,5\cdot5)=5$

$\gcd(69\cdot1,69\cdot5)=69$

$\gcd(420\cdot1,420\cdot5)=420$

$\gcd(1000000000000000\cdot1,1000000000000000\cdot5)=1000000000000000$

-but all of these numbers have the same value of the bigger one divided by the smaller one - 5!!!! Isn't that crazy? In other words, just knowing the *ratio* of two numbers tells you nothing about the size of their gcd. No matter how you try to get around it, arguments based off of ratios here will typically be based on a false premise. Instead, you have to find *greatest* common number, which divides *both of the things*. And in fact, it could be as high as the min of the two. For example, for a prime p, $\gcd(p,a)$ is always equal to $p$ as long as $p$ is a divisor of $a$.

Moreover, it isn't true that the $\gcd$ of two numbers, $a$ and $b$, is less than whatever $\frac{\max(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is, because that would mean that for arbitrary numbers $a$ and $b$

$(\gcd(a,b))^2\le\max(a,b)$

however this isn't always the case. It's a bit weird, but you can even just check this for $a=b$. If $a=b$, $(\gcd(a,a))^2\le\max(a,a)$, $(a)^2\le a$, $a^2\le a$, but sike this doesn't work, since a number isn't generally greater that it's square, unless you're talking about $a=1$

What you *can* say is that $\gcd(a,b)\le\min(a,b)$, though, since any divisor of a number is less than it (or rather, less than or equal to it).

You can also basically "pull things out" of gcd's;

$\gcd(pa,pb)=p\gcd(a,b)$

Now I agree, searching all the way up to the minimum of the two numbers is tedious and stupid. But you can speed things up a bit I suppose by first prime-factoring both numbers. You start by asking if it's divisible by the first prime, 2, and if it is then divide that number by 2 and pull out a two in front of it. Then repeat with 3, 5, and so on. However, even this is still really arduous for large numbers. Once you have that prime factorization, you just look for the largest powers of each prime number that goes into both of them.

In practice, the counterintuive (ish) **Euclidean algorithm** (but you shouldn't just learn about this because its fast - it's also a lit algorithm) is faster for finding gcd's, or at least, so I'm told. The algorithm itself is probably quite simple to set up but it's such a great, interesting, deep result in math.

***Method 1:*** The idea is as follows:

$\gcd(500100,100500)=100\gcd(5001,1005)=300\gcd(67,1667)$. Now, $\gcd(67,1667)=1$. If you keep "pulling out" common factors from the $\gcd$, you will inevitably hit a point where you have to stop and you can't do it anymore. When this happens, the $\gcd$ of the two numbers is 1, because if it weren't, then you *could* pull something else out of it.

***Method 2:*** The Euclidean Algorithm;

$\gcd(500100,100500)=\gcd(500100\text{ mod }100500,100500)=\gcd(500100-402000,100500)=\gcd(98100,100500)=\gcd(98100,100500\text{ mod }98100)=\gcd(98100,100500-98100)=\gcd(98100,2400)=\gcd(98100\text{ mod }2400,2400)=\gcd(98100-96000,2400)=\gcd(2100,2400)=\gcd(300,2400)=\gcd(300,2400)=\gcd(300,0)$, and almost as an artifact, the GCD of anything with 0 is that number, so this is $\gcd(100500,500100)=\gcd(300,0)=300$.

You get the idea the euclidean algorithm just allows you to keep doing things by continuously taking mod's until you get down to something like $\gcd(a,0)$.

***Method 3:*** So using prime factorizations: $100500=100\cdot1005=10^2\cdot\left(5\cdot\frac{1005}{5}\right)=10^2\cdot5\cdot201=(2\cdot5)^2\cdot5\cdot3\cdot\frac{201}{3}=(2\cdot5)^2\cdot5\cdot3\cdot\frac{201}{3}=2^2\cdot5^2\cdot5\cdot3\cdot67$ and 67's prime. So, $100500=2^2\cdot3\cdot5^3\cdot67$. We have the same thing for 500100, so I won't show all the steps. You get $500100=100\cdot5001=2^2\cdot3\cdot5^2\cdot1667$. Remarkably 1667 is prime. If we look at the largest power of 2 which divides both of them, that'd be $2^2$ which is 4. If we look at the largest power of 3 which divides both of them, that'd be $3^1$ which is 3. If we look at the largest power of 5 which divides both of them, that'd be $5^2$ which is 25. Finally, the largest prime powers of 67 and 1667 dividing both of them are to the zeroeth power technically, which is just 1. Multiply of these together, and you get $2^2\cdot3\cdot5^2=3\cdot4\cdot25=3\cdot100=300$.

I understand the point may not to be to use the most efficient algorithm, but one you can create and manage yourself. I respect that. **I think you have some good ideas and you're on the right track.** $\gcd$'s can be weird functions, and behave in strange ways.

I'll add to this as you ask me more things. I know I probably haven't answered this in the best way I can, but I will keep trying.

Comment: But how we can find the maximum possible gcd(a,b) with multiplying one of them to any prime number if we doesn't know anything about gcd?

Comment: If we don't know top limit of these prime numbers how can we find an answer?

Comment: @Jack I've edited my answer. Also, the $\min$ *is* an upper limit to the primes you have to check. If I have $\gcd(5,a)$ - I can multiply $a$ by whatever the heck I want - like 3, 7, 81, 666 - just so long as that thing isn't a multiple of 5, the $\gcd$ will remain the same. That is, $\gcd(5,a)$ is equal to all of $\gcd(5,3a)$, $\gcd(5,7a)$, $\gcd(5,81a)$, and $\gcd(5,666a)$. Notice that your prime, e.g. 5, is the smaller of the two numbers, but also a literal, actual, prime that divides both of them - back in half hour or so

Comment: Sorry, it is a little bit hard to understand. Can you explain it on example like 100500 and 500100?

Comment: @Jack I highlighted three specific methods. I don't know if they're super helpful, but they're somehting.

Comment: If you were referring to the last comment I made before your last one, it wouldn't apply to those two numbers in particular, since neither is prime. What I meant is more like while $\min(a,b)$ is an upper bound on the primes you have to check - (in a worst case scenario, a prime $p$ divides $a$ and $\gcd(a,p)=\min(a,p)=p$), but given more information about the numbers that's not to say you couldn't probably figure out better bounds involving $\max$, and $\min$ functions, I'm just saying that $\gcd(a,b)\le\min(a,b)$ is the only such one I could think of on the spot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136415/discussion-between-pineapple-fish-and-jack).